# Magento 2.0.7 grunt:less problem

Tags: magento2, less, grunt

I'm using DigitalOcean one-click-install **Magento 2.0.7** installation on ubuntu and I have installed nodejs and grunt following the official tutorials. I added my theme to `/dev/tools/grunt/configs/themes.js` like that:

```
    raultheme: {
    area: 'frontend',
    name: 'Raul/raultheme',
    locale: 'et_EE',
    files: [
        'css/styles-m',
        'css/styles-l',
        'css/email',
        'css/email-inline'
    ],
    dsl: 'less'
},
```

All Grunt tasks work except grunt less, which gives the following error: 
[image]

I added `_extends.less` file to `css/source/` and editing this while grunt watch is working is doing nothing.
I don't know what to do anymore, since I followed the tutorial word by word and still get errors. I also did not get any useful information from the github page to what the grunt error sent me.
I have magento running in developer mode, full cache disabled, server side compilation.
Anyone have a clue why I'm getting this error?
Would be really happy if I get this working..

**It gives the same error no matter what theme I try to compile (grunt less:blank etc) so it cant by my theme configuration**

Comment: Also forgot to mention that using grunt:exec my admin css goes missing.

Comment: Check this for grunt configuration [How to compile LESS with Grunt?](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html).

Comment: @DipeshRangani This is for Magento 2.1, but I used the 2.0 tutorial to configure grunt, which is basically the same thing. Still getting errors

Answer (score 0):

Cant belive that no one has had the same issue.. but after a while I found the solution myself.
Running putty(or whatever cli you are using) as an administrator fixed it for me!